# How to set up sendmail without domain on ubuntu for PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, sendmail

I want to make send only server.

So, I did the following.

> apt install sendmail mailutil
>
> sudo sendmailconfig

But, I can not send an mail.

Do you have any suggestions what is missing?

My server is ubuntu 16 without domain.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I did the followings.

```
vi /etc/hosts
```

And

```
#127.0.0.1 localhost                 # comment out
127.0.0.1 ubuntu ubuntu.localdomain  # Added
```

Install libraries for command and php.

```
sudo apt install sendmail mailutils dstat
sudo apt install php-pear
pear install --alldeps Mail
```

Finally

```
sudo reboot
```